# Trying to add link into event click in js - Simplecart

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplecart

I am working on a shopping cart project, and I am using simplecart framework. I am a complete beginner at javascript.

The html:

```
<a class="item_add" href="javascript:;">Add to Cart</a>
```

Basically I would like the href to go to a checkout page for example checkout.html, but the href already has "javascript:;" value for the add the cart function, is there a way of adding to the below that it redirects or directs to checkout.html after adding to cart, I have tried a few things with no avail.

The Js:

```
{ selector: 'shelfItem .item_add'
, event: 'click'
, callback: function () {
var $button = simpleCart.$(this),
fields = {};
... if statements
}
// add the item
simpleCart.add(fields);
}
```

So after the simpleCart.add(fields); is there a way to make it go to another page.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`afterAdd`](http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/afteradd-event) event for that:

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(){
    window.location.href = 'checkout.html'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you're completly done and you think you can safely start a redirect, you can easily do it by changing the href property like this:

`window.location.href = 'http://your-url.com';`

This will start a redirect to your-url.com but might also cut off scripts which are not finished yet.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help this will come in handy in future js projects.